# Active Record Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails application with a mysql database.

I have 2 models: **[foo,bar]** where **foo** *has_many* **bar**

```
$ rails c
foo.all
SELECT `foo`.* FROM `foo`
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `foo`.`id` = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `foo`.`id` = 2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `foo`.`id` = 3
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `foo`.`id` = 4
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `foo`.`id` = 5
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`.`id` = 1
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`.`id` = 2
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`.`id` = 3
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`.`id` = 4
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`.`id` = 5
=> [...]
```

In my application I need to iterate over all of these records, I don't want all these extra sql statements to be made. I only need the data provided by the first SQL statement.

The association exists, but I am the rest of the content dynamically with ajax, so there's no need to do any 'preloading' like ActiveRecord wants to.

Comment: Where did you get that log? For me all on model executes a single sql 
> Offer.all
  Offer Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: In your loop over `@foos` in the view, are you calling `foo.bars.count`? That would cause Rails to lazy load each of the counts as separate SQL queries. If that's the case, you should definitely look into counter caches. http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: 1. I guess you mean Foo.all since Foo is the model
2. It seems like you make it to iterate...overriding some model function maybe? can we see the models?